# A distribution of clocks in different rulers in a 3D plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, tikz-3dplot

Starting, for example as MWE from the answer's Torbjørn T. at this question [plotting a grid like this with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305740/plotting-a-grid-like-this-with-tikz),

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
% draw axis lines
\draw [->] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[below]{$n$};
\draw [->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[left]{$k$};

% place bullets
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
  \foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,2}
     \fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=2pt];

% place ticklabels below x-axis
\foreach \x/\txt in {1/L,2/2L,3/3L}
   \node [below] at (\x,0) {$\txt$};

% place ticklabel for y-axis
\node [left] at (0,2) {$N-1$};

% place 2pi/n-node left of axis
\node [left=1.4cm,inner xsep=0pt] (A) at (0,1) {$\frac{2\pi}{n}$};

% dots on the far right
\node at (4,1) {$\dots$};

% draw lines from fourth and fifth bullet to a coordinate relative to the 2pi/n node
% (vertical separation of bullets is 0.2)
\draw (0, 4*0.2) to[out=180,in=0] ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=2pt]A.south west);
\draw (0, 5*0.2) to[out=180,in=0] ([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=2pt]A.north west);

% draw arrows
\draw [->] (A.north) -- ++(0,0.5cm);
\draw [->] (A.south) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to understand how to draw vertical rods (graduated rulers) of this **1 st picture**

[image]

where the clocks that beat a generic time (rectangle with strange numbers) shall be replaced by simply circular clocks of the type shown in the **2 nd picture**

[image]

With this modality I can change the background color of the clock and of the lancets.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much for edit my scarce English language.

Comment: Typos happen so easily!  So when I'm strolling around, I can't resist correcting it, if only to make it more pleasant to read for potential helpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this? This is 3d.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{Sebastiano/.is family,
Sebastiano/.cd,
minute arm/.style={shorten >=0.5mm},
hour arm/.style={thick,shorten >=1.5mm},
random clock/.style={semithick,fill=white},
clock radius/.initial=5mm}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{20} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,pics/random clock/.style={code={
\tikzset{Sebastiano/.cd,#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mytime}{rnd*720}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\minute}{mod(\mytime,60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hour}{\mytime/5}
\draw[Sebastiano/random clock] (0,0) 
circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Sebastiano/clock radius}];
\draw[Sebastiano/hour arm] (0,0) -- (\hour:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Sebastiano/clock radius});
\draw[Sebastiano/minute arm] (0,0) -- (\minute:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Sebastiano/clock radius});
}},ruler/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 5pt with {\draw (0,-#1/2) -- (0,#1/2);}}}}] 
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
 \draw[double=cyan,double distance=4pt,ruler=4pt] (-4,-2.4) grid[step=pi/2] (4,4);
 \path foreach \X in {-2,...,2} 
  {foreach \Y in {-1,...,2} 
  { (\X*pi/2,\Y*pi/2) pic{random clock={minute arm/.append style={red},
  hour arm/.append style={blue}}}}};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want 3d, just set `\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{00}` to obtain

[image]

I hope the syntac

```
 pic{random clock={minute arm/.append style={red},
  hour arm/.append style={blue}}
```

is self-explanatory. If you want someone who draws "mathematicians axes" then I am not your guy. I explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448048/121799), why. I will be happy to add axes in orthographic projections, but this stuff discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447991/121799) has IMHO no place in a modern textbook. On the blackboard this is still fine.

Comment: The clocks are very nice (perfect)...but thay must to stay in the vertical bars as the 1st picture  in a 3d plane.

Comment: @Sebastiano You only need to adjust the view angle. I added an example.

Comment: 1) Do I think that the hands can be colored using the random command? The same applies to the filling.
2) The clocks (not so many) should be placed on vertical blue rods that are rulers. 
3) These clocks must be in the yz plane (2D) where you can also see the third x coordinate.

Comment: @Sebastiano Can you please provide a sketch of what you want? 1) Of course you can color the hands. They are in the in the commands `\draw[semithick] (0,0) circle[radius=0.5cm];
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (\hour:0.35);`, just try out `\draw[semithick,blue] (0,0) circle[radius=0.5cm];
\draw[thick,red] (0,0) -- (\hour:0.35);` 2) How many? 3) Do you want an orthographic projection or not? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448048/121799 for why I am asking. P.S. Will go to basketball very soon.

Comment: The sketch is the first figure :-(Peraphs my question is it not very clear?

Comment: @Sebastiano Frankly, the sketch is not 100% clear because you said that you do not want to reproduce the sketch. Is it better now?

Comment: In fact, you understand very well and your work is great. Indeed, supreme. I still don't understand how you can create beauties that go beyond the day of my mind. I read the TikZ manual but I think creativity is important. The MWE I wanted to start from was included in the simplest link of your work.

Comment: Hi, when I compile your code severals times the hours and the minutes change automatically?

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes. If you add `\pgfmathsetseed{...}` where `...` is an integer of your choice, at the beginning of the `tikzpicture`, the result should be the same for every compilation.