# A grid in a cartesian plane of clocks using clock package

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, fun, grids

In relation from these question (the first it is mine) [A distribution of clocks in different rulers in a 3D plane](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482498/a-distribution-of-clocks-in-different-rulers-in-a-3d-plane/482511#482511) and [Draw a table of clocks on a plane](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509277/draw-a-table-of-clocks-on-a-plane), what are the best methods to put the clocks of `clock` package randomizing the hours and the minutes in a grid in the cartesian plane?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
    \foreach \j 
    [evaluate=\j as \h using {int(12*rnd)}, 
    evaluate=\j as \m using {int(60*rnd)}]
    in {1,...,10} 
        \node at (\i,\j) {\clock{\h}{\m}};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update: Selection clock style*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage{tikz}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
    \foreach \j 
    [evaluate=\j as \h using {int(12*rnd)}, 
    evaluate=\j as \m using {int(60*rnd)}]
    in {1,...,5} 
        \node[font={\clockfont\ClockStyle=1\ClockFrametrue\Large}] at (\i,\j) {\clock{\h}{\m}};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much. But do I must change in your code to have the circle borders for the clocks? Always thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano You can do it through `font` option in node options or including them into node contents. See the updated answer.

Comment: I have seen now. I not know the technique :-( I'm sorry. However.............MILLE GRAZIE.